# FXM Analytics showing incorrect date

Tags: experience-analytics, fxm

Using `Sitecore 10.2`
I created a local site on Aug 25, 2022, to understand FXM.

In FXM, the data for that site shows as 21 Aug 2022. Is this expected?
Also, when I refresh that local site incognito, I'm expecting the "Visits" in `FXM analytics` would increase. But that is not happening.

[image]

Comment: You are looking at weekly data and the week starts from 21st August Sunday. Change it to Yesterday in filter and see if you are getting right data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Experience Analytics` section go to the date button and click on it. You will see the different-different option there, from where you can choose the day or date for which you want to view the data.

[image]